# How Can I switch On GPS without asking any pop up dialoges?

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how to switch on GPS without asking any pop up dialog's or alerts. Is there a way to do so in android studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start Gps without any popup dialogue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788262/start-gps-without-any-popup-dialogue)

Comment: These pop-ups are there for user security.  Turning them off is a BAD idea.

Comment: @Ankith Prakash even google map asks you to turn on GPS.So for security reasons its not possible now.

Comment: if once we give permission, can we access location pro grammatically afterwords even if the GPS is Off??

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone tell me how to switch on GPS without asking any pop up dialog's or alerts

**AFAIK** this is not Possible due to  security reason

> Is there a way to do so in android studio.

Not Possible

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. There is no way to enable the GPS programmatically. You have to show the permission dialog to the user. It depends on user whether they want to enable GPS or not.