# turn on gps in android using my app without user interaction

Tags: android, gps

I know this is a repeated question but did not found any exact answer to this.

is it possible to turn on gps programmatically in android in any way?

this ques is for all the versions of android till android 6.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It has been answered many times. 
There is [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10302940/3162918) to do that.
You can just request it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15426526/3162918).

Comment: some people says its working some says not.
this is what confusing me...
can somebody clear it out?

Comment: Ok, you can wait for an answer that says it's working, I am the man who says it's not.

Comment: ok thanks anyways..  @bendaf